# Can't group when $$ROOT has no results. (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to score/rank some search results.

Generally this works:
(`userIds` here is a set of IDs representing the users we want scored/ranked and `SomeModel` contains assets associated with those users that give us a sorting criteria.)

```
SomeModel.aggregate([
{$match: {ownerId: {$in:userIds}}},
//Do stuff here to generate a score for the results. This works fine...

...

//at this point you'll have an array like this: {userId:<id>, score:<number>}[]

//push all those results into a field called 'origin' so we can add another
//field with the full set if IDs, merge them, and return them...
{$group: {
_id:0,
origin: {
$push: '$$ROOT'
}
}},

//Add back the full set with project, giving a score of 0 for each.

...

]).then( results => {
//enjoy your results that include all matched IDs plus the
//non-matched ones, who then get a score of 0.
});
```

This all works fine as long as the first `$match` returns some results.  If that `$match` doesn't return any results, the `$group` step doesn't seem to produce anything at all, as where I'd expect it to at least return:

```
{
_id:0,
origin:[]
}
```

...but it doesn't.  If I look at my results at this point I just get `[]`.

I have tried to change that `$group` step to check for this like this:

```
            {$group: { //make these an array so we can merge it....
                _id:0,
                origin: {
                    $push :{
                        $cond:{
                            if: {$eq:[{$size : '$$ROOT'}, 0]},
                            then: [null],
                            else: '$$ROOT'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }},
```

...but then I get the error "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: object".

What is the correct way to do this?  To be clear, I want to create a container object that holds the results up that point in the pipeline as an array in the field `origin`.  (Then I'm able to concatenate these with the full list I started with and get a proper sorted list).

This works if the pipeline currently contains results, but if it doesn't the group step does nothing.

**Desired inputs / outputs:**

My problem is specifically with the `$group` stage so I'll focus on that.

***Example 1:***
This example is working correctly with the above code.

input:

```
[ {ownerId: <ID A>, score: 234}, {ownerId: <ID B>, score: 265}]
```

`$group`

Desired output:

```
[{
    _id:0,
    origin:[ {ownerId: <ID A>, score: 234}, {ownerId: <ID B>, score: 265}]

}]
```

Actual output: Matches!

***Example 2:***
This example is NOT working correctly with the above code.

input:

```
[]
```

`$group`

Desired output:

```
[{
    _id:0,
    origin:[]

}]
```

Actual output:

```
[]
```

Comment: What's the exact requested output for the different scenarios?

Comment: Updated to provide examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of an aggregate pipeline is that when executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. "Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. In the above Mongo executes the pipeline as follows:

```
collection | $match | $group | $project => result
```

This means if the `$match` step doesn't match any documents in the pipeline with the given condition, Mongo will not pipe anything further, hence you get an empty result because the pipeline ends with the `$match`, it doesn't go further.

What you can do however is inject the condition within the `$group` pipeline but that will incur some performance hit given a large collection. This is because the `$group` step will be processing all the documents in the collection instead of reducing the number of documents getting into the pipeline by returning just those docs which match the condition as a first priority using `$match`.

With this route, consider your `$group` stage as the first pipeline step with the condition:

```
[
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "origin": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$in": ["$ownerId", userIds] },
                    "$$ROOT", null
                ]
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "origin": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$origin",
                "as": "el",
                "cond": { "$ne": ["$$el", null] }
            }
        }
    } }
]
```

Comment: I see - that makes sense.  Given that, I can just detect for this case at the end and construct my own results list outside of mongo (since I'd just be adding 'score:0' to each id in the list, I imagine it would be less of a hit than grouping for each one).

Comment: The best option would be to continue with the current pipeline but check the result array if it's empty you can push the desired final document to that empty array e.g `if (result.length === 0) result.push({ _id: 0, origin: [] });`

Comment: Any chance you can show this in the context of the surrounding pipeline stages?  I didn't realize you could just manipulate the results inline like that without terminating the pipeline.  I'll accept this if I can see what you're saying here - it sounds like I'm missing something valuable.

Comment: I meant after executing the pipeline, when the Promise resolves i.e. at the stage `SomeModel.aggregate([ ... ]).then(results => { if (result.length === 0) result.push({ _id: 0, origin: [{ score: 0 }] }); });`